# How to render block conditionally using vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     products:[
       {
        product_id:'21221312',
        product:[
          {variation:'paper', price:'12'}
         ]
        },
        {
        product_id:'2122131212',
        product:[
          {variation:'ebook', price:'122'}
         ]
        },
         {
        product_id:'21221312212',
        product:[
          {variation:'aduio', price:'1322'}
         ]
        }, 
     ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(product, index) in products">
    <div v-for="variant in product.product">
      <p v-if="variant.variation === 'paper'">
        {{variant.price}}
      </p>
       <p v-if="variant.variation==='ebook'">
        {{variant.price}}
      </p>
        <p v-if="variant.variation==='aduio'">
        {{variant.price}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

I am just start learning Vue.js, I have this problem how i can to render variation price conditionally, for example if variation contains `paper` i want to render only paper not `ebook and audio`, is this possible with  `v-if` satement?

```js
 products:[
      {
    product_id:'21221312'
    variations: [
      {
        variation:'paper',
        price:'44'
      },
      {
        variation:'ebook',
        price:'41'
      },
      {
        variation:'audio',
        price:'40'
      }
    ],

    },
    
    {
    product_id:'212213132'
    variations: [
      {
        variation:'paper',
        price:'44'
      },
      {
        variation:'ebook',
        price:'41'
      },
      {
        variation:'audio',
        price:'40'
      }
    ],
   },   
 ]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, Sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: Your code has a simple issue, which is in the last p tag you are just using `if` instead of `v-if`. Also, whenever we are using `for` loop, then we should also use a key with it, which needs to be unique. `v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are writing your markup is redundant, whether it be audio, ebook, or paper, it will still just render the price. might as well remove all those v-ifs since they all end up doing the same thing. You can display everything inside the variant and it will display correctly what the product has.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(product, index) in products">
     
    <div v-for="variant in product.product">
     <p>
     Type: {{variant.variation}} | Price: {{variant.price}}
     </p>
     <p>
    
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

You can check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fex3s2u9/1/) of your issue to see how it works and play around with it if you would like